# Muon life-time in laboratory frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics

I have a question about a task I am supposed to solve:
A muon with rest mass $m_{\mu}=105 \space MeV/c^2$, has at creation a velocity of $0.1$ $c_{0}$ in the direction of an electric field of $20\space kV/m$ of magnitude, what is the average lifetime in the laboratory frame, if the decay time is $\tau_{\mu}$=2.2 $\mu s $ (Meassured in the frame of the muon).

I know that $E \space e_{0}$$=\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma m v)$, so $v(t)=\frac{A^2}{1+\frac {A^2}{c^2}}$, where $A=\frac{e_{0}\space E\space t}{m_\mu}$+$\gamma_{0}v_{0}$,

$\gamma_{0}$ and $v_{0}$ are $\gamma(t)$ and $v(t)$ at $t=0$,

I substitute this into the expression for $\gamma (t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{v(t)^2}{c^2}}}$ and this into $dt=\gamma \space d\tau$ where t is the laboratory time and $\tau $ is the time in the frame of the particle. I then integrate this, get a expression with arcsinh[u],and finaly get the laboratory time to be $6.42 \mu s$, the book says it's $2.23 \mu s$. I triple-checked everything and done the whole thing with Wolfram Mathematica. 
Am I missing something or is the book wrong?